# OpenCSV with Java spring boot can't read values of first column

Tags: java, spring-boot, csv, opencsv

I am trying to read values from csv file with Java spring boot with dependency of opencsv. But the values of first column are not geting readed while other columns are fine. It returns them as null.

```
        Reader reader = Files.newBufferedReader(Paths.get(path));
        CsvToBean<CsvBikeTrips> csvToBean = new CsvToBeanBuilder(reader)
                    .withType(CsvBikeTrips.class)
                    .withIgnoreLeadingWhiteSpace(false)
                    .build();
        List<CsvBikeTrips> csvBikeTrips = csvToBean.parse();
```

```
public class CsvBikeTrips {
    @CsvBindByName(column = "Departure")
    private String departureTimestamp;
    @CsvBindByName(column = "Return")
    private String returnTimestamp;
    @CsvBindByName(column = "Departure station id")
    private String departureStationId;
    @CsvBindByName(column = "Return station id")
    private String returnStationId;
    @CsvBindByName(column = "Departure station name")
    private String departureStationName;
    @CsvBindByName(column = "Return station name")
    private String returnStationName;
    @CsvBindByName(column = "Covered distance (m)")
    private String coveredDistance;
    @CsvBindByName(column = "Duration (sec.)")
    private String duration;

    public String getDepartureTimestamp() {
        return departureTimestamp;
    }

    public void setDepartureTimestamp(String departureTimestamp) {
        this.departureTimestamp = departureTimestamp;
    }

    public String getReturnTimestamp() {
        return returnTimestamp;
    }

    public void setReturnTimestamp(String returnTimestamp) {
        this.returnTimestamp = returnTimestamp;
    }

    public String getDepartureStationId() {
        return departureStationId;
    }

    public void setDepartureStationId(String departureStationId) {
        this.departureStationId = departureStationId;
    }

    public String getReturnStationId() {
        return returnStationId;
    }

    public void setReturnStationId(String returnStationId) {
        this.returnStationId = returnStationId;
    }

    public String getDepartureStationName() {
        return departureStationName;
    }

    public void setDepartureStationName(String departureStationName) {
        this.departureStationName = departureStationName;
    }

    public String getReturnStationName() {
        return returnStationName;
    }

    public void setReturnStationName(String returnStationName) {
        this.returnStationName = returnStationName;
    }

    public String getCoveredDistance() {
        return coveredDistance;
    }

    public void setCoveredDistance(String coveredDistance) {
        this.coveredDistance = coveredDistance;
    }

    public String getDuration() {
        return duration;
    }

    public void setDuration(String duration) {
        this.duration = duration;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "CsvBikeTrips{" +
                    "departureTimestamp='" + departureTimestamp + '\'' +
                    ", returnTimestamp='" + returnTimestamp + '\'' +
                    ", departureStationId='" + departureStationId + '\'' +
                    ", returnStationId='" + returnStationId + '\'' +
                    ", departureStationName='" + departureStationName + '\'' +
                    ", returnStationName='" + returnStationName + '\'' +
                    ", coveredDistance='" + coveredDistance + '\'' +
                    ", duration='" + duration + '\'' +
                    '}';
    }
}
```

And the row of csv files look like this:

```
Departure,Return,Departure station id,Departure station name,Return station id,Return station name,Covered distance (m),Duration (sec.)
2021-05-31T23:57:25,2021-06-01T00:05:46,094,Laajalahden aukio,100,Teljäntie,2043,500
2021-05-31T23:56:59,2021-06-01T00:07:14,082,Töölöntulli,113,Pasilan asema,1870,611
```

Ive tried something like this:

```
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                    new FileInputStream(path), "UTF-8"));
```

And also to save the file in different txt editors but no success.

Comment: `System.out.println(csvBikeTrips.get(0));` prints what please?

Comment: Seems that issue was in the files. I converted them with online converter to UTF-8 and it works. I just wonder how this could be done programmatically with just reading the file.

Comment: Well you'd need to read the file in the encoding that was used on it, instead of the UTF-8 which you just said you had to convert it *to* before your code works

Comment: I checked the old file and the file info says that it's also UTF-8. Basically, I did the conversion from UTF-8 to UTF-8 . I don't get it :\

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It happens that the file, in the beginning, had something like : `ZWNBSP`
Intelli J editor couldn't see that easily. It seems that it is related to BOM.

Unicode of that is `\uFEFF`

Fix:

```
InputStream input = new FileInputStream(path);
        Reader reader = new InputStreamReader(new BOMInputStream(input), StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
```

Comment: You should explain that the major difference in approach that you had mistaken at first is usage of "BOMInputStream" that you used in the solution and was wrong in the question:`new InputStreamReader(new BOMInputStream(input)`

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).